# Test if a node matches a MongoDb query

Tags: mongodb, jackson, mongojack

I would like to test if a Jackson node matches a set of conditions, expressed with MongoDb [query operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/) (or eventually MongoJack's [DBQuery](http://mongojack.org/apidocs/org/mongojack/DBQuery.html) objects)

Is there an out-of-the-box solution that I've missed, or should I build it myself ?

Sample interface:

```
 /**
  * Tests if context matches the set of conditions, expressed as MongoDb query operators
  * @return true if it matches
  */
  public boolean isMatch(JsonNode context, JsonNode conditions) {
     ....
  }
```